# Blocked loading resource from url not allowed by $sceDelegate policy. URL: \\server\\directory\file.html

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've done some reading online and it seems like you need to whitelist the url that is being called.  Here is my code:

```
//Get the module.
var application = angular.module('editApp'); 

//Create the directive
application.directive("testDirective", function () {
    return {
        templateUrl: "\\\\server\\directory\\file.html"
    };
});
//Add the url to the whitelist.
application.config(function ($sceDelegateProvider) {
    $sceDelegateProvider.resourceUrlWhitelist(['self','\\\\server\\directory\\file.html']);
});
```

Is there something that I am missing?  I thought I read all of the documentation correctly and followed other responses on stackoverflow to-a-T.

Comment: I don't think you should be using Windows style paths.  Angular only understands web URLs paths which use Unix (`/`) style delimiters.  Can you try with those?  And make sure that you are providing URLs, not filepaths.  Additionally, and just for sanity, you are not using the `file://` protocol correct?

Comment: Can you point your web server to the file share and serve the file that way instead of having the client attempt to connect to it?

Comment: Correct, I am not using file protocol.  Also, I don't believe I can point the web server to the file share.

Comment: It seems to be working with the URL path now.  Thanks for the help!